# What is the difference between knife-solo and knife-zero?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

It seems like knife-solo and knife-zero are similar. What are the main differences between them and which one is considered more idiomatic to use in the case where I don't want to setup a chef server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One uses chef-solo the other uses chef-client in local mode. Local mode is probably a better bet if you are starting from scratch, but expect some rough edges as a Chef Server really is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hesitant to be introduced the Chef-Server, I recommend that you try to first use the Knife-Zero.

As coderange say, since it is based on the Chef-Zero. And it makes to be able to migrate to Chef-Server later.

https://knife-zero.github.io/tips/migrate_between_chefserver/